# Rails - two attributes one input field - Whats the Syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need this html output from my form

```
 <input class="text valid" id="contacts_custom_field_phone_number_50754" name="contacts[custom_field][phone_number_50754]" size="30" type="text">
```

this is what i got so far

```
= f.label "Phone"
%br    
= f.text_field :custom_field=>{:phone_number_50754=>"123-213-2134"}
```

this is obviously wrong but it works in my rails console and posts the data to the API

how do i write the code to get the output that i need?

when i do this in the rails console

```
  :custom_field=>{:phone_number_50754=>"123-123-2134"}
```

it posts to the API

Comment: Is that a nested resource called `CustomField`?

Comment: I'm having trouble following what you're asking. What are you trying to output? Give examples of what you're entering and then expecting to be output.

Comment: @ChrisPeters All i want to do is get the code to output <input id="contacts_custom_field_phone_number_50754" name="contacts[custom_field][phone_number_50754]">

Comment: @ChrisPeters - what i entered is = f.text_field :custom_field=>{:phone_number_50754=>"123-213-2134"}

Comment: @ChrisCashwell - im not using a nested resource....im just trying to hit this FRESHDESK API

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`fields_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for):

```
- f.fields_for :custom_field do |custom_fields|
  = custom_fields.text_field :phone_number_50754
```